# How can you control access to objects in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

Imagine I have a Device class. I don't want the programmer to be able to instantiate his own Device objects so now I create a DeviceManager class. The DeviceManager is the only entity that will be instantiated and gives the programmer access to Device objects by having the programmer specify an ID of some sort. This way, only the DeviceManager class needs to be cleaned up by the programmer and no stray Device objects are left behind. My main concern is how to control access to objects in the interest of studious garbage collection. Is a "manager" pattern like I've described a good idea in C++? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need it, yes.

To achieve this control, you can make the constructor of the `Device` `private` and declare `DeviceManager` as protected in the `Device` class.

```
class Device
{
private: //not necessary, private by default
   Device();

friend class DeviceManager;
};

class DeviceManager
{
public:
   Device* getDevice();
};
```

You could also return a smart pointer to a `Device` (recommended) and keep created devices inside the `DeviceManager`, depending on what you need.

This is called the instance manager pattern. The `DeviceManager` is also a factory of devices.

Also, C++ doesn't have garbage collection, but if you use a smart pointer you needn't worry about memory management.

Comment: Except I would **not** return a pointer to a device. Return a reference if the DeviceManager manages the lifespan or return a smart pointer to indicate ownership sharing semantics to the caller, thus indicating if the caller take/share ownership of the returned device.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using Private Constructor.
A Private constructor is a special kind of constructor.It is commonly used in classes that contain static members only.If a class has one or more private constructors and no public constructors then other classes are not allowed to create instances of this class.
For e.g

```
class abc
{
private abc()
{}

}
```

The declaration of the empty constructor prevents the automatic generation of a default constructor. Note that if you don't use an access modifier with the constructor it will still be private by default. However, the private modifier is usually used explicitly to make it clear that the class cannot be instantiated.

Private constructors are used to prevent the creation of instances of a class when there are no instance fields or methods, such as the Math class, or when a method is called to obtain an instance of a class. If all the methods in the class are static, consider making the entire class static.